# How can I get output from Reduce assigned to a variable?

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation, assignment

I use Reduce to solve an 3rd order equation, and the output is given as the OR'd combination the solution variable.  Normally, I can do a replacement to assign the value to a variable, but that doesn't work on Reduce.  I found that I need to use ToRules to do so, but I still can't get it to work.

```
Vout = Vin/(C1*C2*L1*R1*s^3 + C1*R1*s + C2*L1*s^2 + C2*R1*s + 1) 
s = I ω;
values = {
  R1 -> 2000,
  C1 -> 10e-9,
  L1 -> 500u,
  C2 -> 1.2n
};   
sol2 = Reduce[ComplexExpand[Im[Vout/Vin /. values]] = =0, ω]
```

Here's what I see in my notebook:

[image]

Normally, I'd do

```
ω = (ω /. sol2[[3])
```

to grab the 3rd item from the similar list resulting from `Solve`.  However, `Reduce` doesn't provide a list, so it doesn't work. How do I use `ToRules` correctly? Or is there another way to grab a specific output from the expression returned by `Reduce`?

Comment: Have you seen `ToRules`?

Comment: Try `{ToRules[sol2]}[[3]]` instead.

Comment: Also `\[Omega] /. Solve[sol2, \[Omega]]`

Comment: Or just use `Solve`, e.g., `sol2 = Solve[ComplexExpand[Im[Vout/Vin /. (values // Rationalize)]] == 0, \[Omega]]`. In some cases you may wish/need to add the option `Method -> Reduce`

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit --> that worked! thanks!  If you offer the solution as an answer,  I can give you the proper credit.

Comment: @Jason B --that also works.  Thank you.

Comment: @BobHanlon, I could not get yours to work.   Thank you.

Comment: What version are you using? And did you try adding the option Method -> Reduce?

Answer (score 3):

It is recommend to use `Rationalize@1.2` instead of `1.2` in `Reduce` or `Solve`

```
Clear["`*"];
Vout = Vin/(C1*C2*L1*R1*s^3 + C1*R1*s + C2*L1*s^2 + C2*R1*s + 1);
s = I ω;
values = {R1 -> 2000, C1 -> 10 e - 9, L1 -> 500 u, 
   C2 -> Rationalize@1.2 n};
sol2 = Reduce[ComplexExpand[Im[Vout/Vin /. values]] == 0, ω]
sol3 = Solve[ComplexExpand[Im[Vout/Vin /. values]] == 0, ω]
```

Maybe you use the old version of Mathematica. Here we test the method  provided by @SjoerdSmit

```
sol2 // ToRules // List

(* {{u -> 0, 
  e -> -(3/50) (-15 + 2 n)}, {ω -> -(Sqrt[-45 + 50 e + 6 n]/
    Sqrt[-27000 n u + 30000 e n u])}, {ω -> 
   Sqrt[-45 + 50 e + 6 n]/Sqrt[-27000 n u + 30000 e n u]}, {n -> 0, 
  e -> 9/10}, {ω -> 0}}
 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never used `ToRules` myself, but it looks like it's a very old function. Anyway, it seems like it has the strange convention to convert `Or` (`||`) into a `Sequence`:

```
ToRules[x == 1 || y == 1]
(* Sequence[{x -> 1}, {y -> 1}] *)
```

This is rather unusual; hardly any function in WL ever returns a `Sequence`. `And` (`&&`) , on the other hand, gets converted to a `List`:

```
ToRules[x == 1 && y == 1]
(* {x -> 1, y -> 1} *)
```

So it looks like you're expected to wrap the returned value of `ToRules` in a list in order to get something similar to what `Solve` returns (a list of lists of rules).

Thus, to access the 3rd solution, you need:

```
{ToRules[sol2]}[[3]]
```